How to dynamically retrieve the content text of a HTML tag and its child tags?
I would like to know how to dynamically retrieve the content text of a HTML tag and its child tags?
Here is my HTML code, for example:


<p><code>C:\<select>
        <option value="test1\">test1\</option>
        <option value="test2\">test2\</option>
    </select>test3\<select>
        <option value="test4\">test4\</option>
        <option value="test5\">test5\</option>
    </select>test6\<select>
        <option value="test7\">test7\</option>
        <option value="test8\">test8\</option>
        <option value="test9\">test9\</option>
    </select>test10.txt</code></p>



I would like to create a button after this code, and when it is clicked, I would like to write the content directly within the console.
For example:
C:\test2\test3\test4\test6\test8\test10.txt

or
C:\test1\test3\test5\test6\test9\test10.txt

...
It might be possible that another paragraph of code only contains 1 or 2 <select> tags. So, I don't want a code that only works for 3 <select> tags, like in the previous example.
Thank you very much in advance

What have you tried to achieve this?

element.innerText will get the text of the element and all its children.

Do you want the button once pressed to retrieve the selected options as in a file path as you wrote?

I've tried using innerHTML and innerText but it's not working. InnerText just give me the content of the code tag, not the select tags.

@Mehdi yess I would like to retrieve the full path for example, with the content of the code tag and the content of the select tags. But I don't find any solution to my problem to get it dynamically

@AntoineHazebrouck innerText works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/2n6e5twc/

Do you only want the selected options from the dropdowns? That's not what your question says. The content is the text of all the options, not just the selected ones.

The best property to use if you want all the text (ie. both inside and outside the <select> elements) is .textContent:
p.textContent; // C:\ test1\ test2\ test3\ test4\ test5\ test6\ test7\ test8\ test9\ test10.txt


Working Example:


let firstParagraph = document.querySelector('p');
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let outputParagraph = document.querySelector('.output');
let selectElements = document.querySelectorAll('select');

const showOutput = () => {
  let outputText = '';

  // GET *ALL* PATH SEGMENTS
  let pathSegmentsArray = firstParagraph.textContent.split(' ').filter((pathSegment) => pathSegment !== '');

  // GET PATH SEGMENTS INSIDE <select> ELEMENTS
  let selectedOptions = [];
  selectElements.forEach((select) => selectedOptions.push(select.selectedOptions[0].textContent));

  // BUILD OUTPUT
  pathSegmentsArray.forEach((pathSegment) => {
    let includePathSegment = false;
    
    if (firstParagraph.innerText.includes(pathSegment.trim())) {
      includePathSegment = true;
    }
    
    if (selectedOptions.includes(pathSegment.trim())) {
      includePathSegment = true;
    }
    
    if (includePathSegment) {
      outputText += pathSegment;
    }
  });
  
  outputParagraph.textContent = outputText;
}

button.addEventListener('click', showOutput);
<p><code>C:\<select>
        <option value="test1\">test1\</option>
        <option value="test2\">test2\</option>
    </select>test3\<select>
        <option value="test4\">test4\</option>
        <option value="test5\">test5\</option>
    </select>test6\<select>
        <option value="test7\">test7\</option>
        <option value="test8\">test8\</option>
        <option value="test9\">test9\</option>
    </select>test10.txt</code></p>
    
<button type="button">Show Output</button>
<p class="output"></p>




Further Reading on textContent vs innerText:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

The source above states:

Differences from innerText
Don't get confused by the differences between Node.textContent and > HTMLElement.innerText. Although the names seem similar, there are > important differences:



textContent gets the content of all elements, including
<script> and <style> elements. In contrast, innerText only
shows "human-readable" elements.
textContent returns every element in the node. In contrast,
innerText is aware of styling and won't return the text of
"hidden" elements.



Moreover, since innerText takes CSS styles into account, reading
the value of innerText triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date
computed styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus > should be avoided when possible.)


Further Reading on selectedOptions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions


I don't think that is what the OP wants he wants to retrieve only the selected option. In this case even if you select test1 you output test2 as well

Yes exactly, I would like to retrieve the full path with the selected options, not all the options.

@AntoineHazebrouck - Aha. I understand the issue better now. I have updated the Working Example above.

@Rounin thank you very much, it works like a charm

I think the best way will be to use select even for c:, test3... and just change their appearance not to look as a select field (using 'noselect' class). Then you will need to use the selected attribute to be able to get the default value of the unchanged Select HTML tag. Then I first get all the default value and look for the changed Select tag with corresponding eventListener and finaly change this value in the defaulValue array using the index


const selects = document.querySelectorAll('select')
let arrayDefault = []
let arrayChanged = []


selects.forEach(select=>{
    let defaultValue = select.querySelector('option[selected]').value;
    arrayDefault.push(defaultValue)
})



selects.forEach((select,index)=>select.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
    let selectedValue = select.value
    console.log(arrayDefault)
    console.log(arrayDefault[index])
    let newArrayDefault = arrayDefault.map((elem,idx)=>{
        return (index===idx) ? arrayDefault[idx]=selectedValue : arrayDefault[idx]=arrayDefault[idx]
    })
    console.log(newArrayDefault)
    console.log(newArrayDefault.join(''))

})
)
.noselect{
    border: none;
    appearance: none;
}
        <code>
            <select class="noselect">
                <option value="C:\" selected>C:\</option>
            </select>
            <select>
                <option value="test1\" selected>test1\</option>
                <option value="test2\">test2\</option>
            </select>
            <select class="noselect">
                <option value="test3\" selected>test3\</option>
            </select>
            <select>
                <option value="test4\" selected>test4\</option>
                <option value="test5\" >test5\</option>
            </select>
            <select class="noselect">
                <option value="test6\" selected>test6\</option>
            </select>
            <select>
                <option value="test7\" selected>test7\</option>
                <option value="test8\">test8\</option>
                <option value="test9\">test9\</option>
            </select>
            <select class="noselect">
                <option value="test10.txt\"  selected>test10.txt\</option>
            </select>
        </code>




You very welcome  and glad that it helped! Enjoy coding!
